# Solve triple integral and draw graph

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I need to solve this triple integral:
$$\iiint y^2\exp(2xy)\, dx\,dy\,dz$$
Where $$V=\{x=0,y=1,z=0,y=x,z=8\}$$

My answer $\exp(2)-1$ was wrong

I adjusted my limits: $x$ from $0$ to $y$, $y$ from $x$ to $1$, $z$ from $0$ to $8$ and got answer:
$$2x^2 - \exp(2x^2)+\exp(2)-2$$But I still have no idea whether it is right or how to draw a proper graph

Here is link to my attempt of solving it
https://fex.net/ru/s/prpd5ep

Comment: If you show us how you got your answer, we can find your mistake.

Comment: I can't add photos to my answer. I will try to make a link to my solution

Comment: you have to adjust the endpoint of the integrals

Comment: You've integrated each of $x,\,y$ from $0$ to $1$, whereas if I've correctedly understood the problem statement $y$ should be from $x$ to $1$.

Comment: I adjusted my limits: x from 0 to y, y from x to 1, z from 0 to 8 and got answer: 2x^2 - exp(2x^2)+exp(2)-2. But I still have no idea whether it is right

Comment: Going forward, once you are able to create an electronic copy of the image, as in this case, if your operating system has a **screen capture** utility, (e.g. perhaps print screen key on keyboard) then you can create and save a graphics file (i.e. a *.jpg file) on your hard disk.  Then, when writing your query, you can use the image icon on the toolbar to insert the image into the query.  Note, that this is **not** the preferred way of presenting math.  If possible, please use [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to insert mathematics into the query.

Comment: The answer shouldn't depend on $x$ when you're done. Could you define $V$ with inequalities, so the integration region is unambiguous?

Answer (score 1):

so, what we have is:
$$0\le z\le8$$
and since this variable is separable we can say:
$$I=\int_0^8dz\iint y^2\exp(2xy)dxdy=8\iint y^2\exp(2xy)dxdy$$

---

Now the lines $x=0,y=1,y=x$ forms a triangular region which I assume is the domain you want. In this region $0\le x,y\le1$ is true but we need to put the limits on properly:
$$I=8\int_0^1\int_0^yy^2\exp(2xy)dxdy$$
$$I=8\int_0^1y^2\left[\frac{\exp(2xy)}{2y}\right]_{x=0}^ydy=4\int_0^1y\left(e^{2y^2}-1\right)dy$$
$$I=4\int_0^1ye^{2y^2}dy-4\int_0^1ydy$$